# Lost NSTouches when OS X Lion steals event

Tags: cocoa, events, osx-lion, nsview

I have found that it is possible to put a multi-touch Cocoa app into a weird state in OS X Lion, when the system detects a gesture (such as switching Spaces or moving to Exposé). Basically, I end up seeing the touches with phases NSTouchPhaseBegan and NSTouchPhaseMoved, but when the gesture kicks in, I get absolutely no more information about those touch events (no touchesEnded or touchesCancelled).

I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to detect that these events were cancelled and I should take their visual counterparts off of the screen.  It's really noticable with the five finger pinch gesture that initiates Mission Control; I get five balls on the screen representing my touches, they move for a bit, Mission Control Begins, and the balls are stuck on the screen because I don't ever receive a touchesCancelled for those touches (and other touches are new touches, with different memory addresses).

So, background information: an NSView subclass with `[self setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES]` and `[self setWantsRestingTouches:YES]`.  I have tried listening for an NSWorkspace notification that would help me infer when to cleanup my touches dictionary, but I don't seem to get anything at the time the system takes over.